# Unable to get auto compliation to work in ASP.NET 5

Tags: compilation, asp.net-core

I've downloaded the latest Visual Studio 2015 CTP but am unable to get auto compilation to work. I'm trying this,

1. Create a web application in visual studio.
2. Launch it web ctrl+f5
3. Change some cs file
4. Hit f5 in the browser
5. Observe the change

And nothing happens. I still need to go back to VS and build to see any changes.

Anyone knows why and what I'm missing?

I have read a few threads here on StackOverflow and in all of them the problem seems that the debugger is attached. But that's not the case for me, I start the application either by ctrl+f5 or Debug -> Start without debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out why it wasn't working. I was running Windows 10 in a VM (using Parallels on a mac), and the created project was saved in a shared drive with the path something like this,

\psf\Home\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects...

And I guess the file watcher wasn't able to detect file changes and therefore the auto compile wasn't working. I have now created a new project and saved it on c: and the auto compile is working!